# Merging multiple dataframes based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1

```
symbol  date        .    .    .     close   .     1d     2d      3d      5d   10d   20d
a     01/02/20120.  .    .    .      100    .     2      2.5    4.1     1.9   4.65  9.12
a     01/02/20120.  .    .    .      60     .     1.1    2.3    2.1     4.9   3.62  7.10
.
.
.
ab    01/02/20120.  .    .    .      55     .    8      2.15   7.8     1.9   4.65  9.12
ab    01/02/20120.  .    .    .      22     .    4.4    2.5    1.1     1.9   4.65  9.12
.
.

ac    01/02/20120.  .    .    .      67     .    2      2.5.   4.1     1.9   4.65  9.12
.
.
.
```

and a dataframe df2

```
symbol  .   .   .   .   release_date    release_time    .   .    .   .  .   . 
a       .   .   .   .   01/02/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
a       .   .   .   .   01/05/20120       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
a       .   .   .   .   01/09/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
a       .   .   .   .   01/011/2020       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
ab      .   .   .   .   01/02/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ab      .   .   .   .   01/05/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ac      .   .   .   .   01/18/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ad      .   .   .   .   01/20/20120       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
```

I want to add new columns to df2 such that

if release_time = a, then search df1 for the entry having same release_date as df2 and add columns `close`, `1d`,`2d`,`3d`,`5d`,`10d`,`20d` for that particular date. I dont want other columns from df1 to be part of the dataframe and keep all the columns of df2 at the same time.

if release_time = b, then close value for the date before that, if not present I would like to add NA to the column

Expected output :

```
symbol  .   .   .   .   release_date    release_time    .   .    .   .  .   .  close   1d  2d  3d  5d  10d  20d 
a       .   .   .   .   01/02/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .   
a       .   .   .   .   01/05/20120       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
a       .   .   .   .   01/09/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
a       .   .   .   .   01/011/2020       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
ab      .   .   .   .   01/02/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ab      .   .   .   .   01/05/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ac      .   .   .   .   01/18/20120       a             .   .    .   .  .   .
ad      .   .   .   .   01/20/20120       b             .   .    .   .  .   .
```

I tried doing this with

```
merged_left = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df1, how='left', left_on='release_date', right_on='date')
merged_left
```

This provides me data merged in the df2 and I am not sure how to add the filter for release_time = a or b.

can anyone help me with the same

UPDATE - Here is the link to how dataframe look like : [Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MwXMDZ8hSLQcv1qBy4cpDszmsWm-lcSaYh6nUGUwWNM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: Could you make your description more general and include the code so we can quickly reproduce what you are working on? E.g. provide us with `df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ['01/02/20120','01/02/20120'],'close':[100,60]})`

Comment: hi @Eric I have added the google sheet link to the update on the question.

Comment: The google sheet is not publically accessible, and that still requires us to create the DataFrame.

Comment: @Eric My apologies I cannot share the data and thats why I create these dummy sheets so that problem is understandable. I have change the link access, you should be able to view it now.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood what you want to do  but to make the filter for the date instead of just passing the whole dataframe to the merge() function you should pass something like this `df[ df['release_date'] == a]`